# Size of L1 cache

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-cache

Typically, how big is L1 cache today?

Comment: See - http://superuser.com/questions/72209/why-has-the-size-of-l1-cache-not-increased-very-much-over-the-last-20-years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interesting article on Wikipedia for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_%28microarchitecture%29

> 64 KB L1 cache/core (32 KB L1 Data + 32 KB L1 Instruction) and 256 KB L2 cache/core.